# Easiest way to give an object with fields methods from a constructor Javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this code

```
var point = function(x,y,color)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.moveRight = function(dx)
    {
         this.x += dx;
    }
}
var objectWithoutMethods = {
    x : 4,
    y : 2,
    color : '#392f44'
}
```

Is it possible to make the field moveRight of objectWithoutMethods the same moveRight method in the constructor of point?
I'm trying to give a parsed object it's functions back since json.stringify doesn't store functions

I'm sorry if this was asked somewhere else already; I'm new to javascript.

Comment: Give in what way?

Comment: If you want to just add that function to the `objectWithoutMethods` then yes, just add it:`moveRight :function(dx)`. Functions are first class objects in Javascript

Comment: It's very unclear what exactly you want to do here and why?

Comment: worth point out that there are no constructors here

Comment: so I have to type out the same function again? or can I somehow cast objectwithoutmethods into a point?

Comment: The thing is that JavaScript is not strictly an object oriented language. The function you use as a constructor is not a constructor like in other languages but it acts more like a closure. Making this.VARIABLE inner to that closure.

Comment: @Liam `point` can be regarded as a constructor.

Comment: @SebastianSimon no, [this is a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)

Comment: @Liam This `point` is an old-school constructor using the prototypal pattern. It is intended to be invoked with `new`. Since `function`-keyword functions can both be normal functions and constructors, and this looks just like a constructor, you actually can call it a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

```js
const thing = {
  x: 4,
  y: 2,
  color: '#392f44',
  moveRight: function(dx = 3) {
    //         ^ note: if you use properties of this object
    //           this can not be a arrow function ('this' 
    //           will not be in scope)
    this.x += dx;
  },
  point: function(x = this.x, y = this.y, color = this.color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
  }
};

function setColor(color) {
  this.color = color || this.color;
  //                 ^ if no value given, use the current value
}

// set from function
thing.setColor = setColor;

// set directly
thing.setX = function(x) {
  this.point(23);
  //         ^ we can do this because of the default values 
  //           in the thing.point method ;)
}

console.log(`x ${thing.x}, y: ${thing.y}, color: ${thing.color}`);

thing.point(5, 8);
console.log(`x ${thing.x}, y: ${thing.y}, color: ${thing.color}`);

thing.setColor('#000');
console.log(`x ${thing.x}, y: ${thing.y}, color: ${thing.color}`);

thing.moveRight(5);
console.log(`x ${thing.x}, y: ${thing.y}, color: ${thing.color}`);

thing.setX(23);
console.log(`x ${thing.x}, y: ${thing.y}, color: ${thing.color}`);
```

If you intend to create more instances of the same object, consider using a real constructor:

```js
const initializePrototype = (ctor, extensions) => {
  Object.entries(extensions).forEach(([key, method]) => 
    ctor.prototype[key] = method );
  ctor.prototype.isSet = true;
};

function Something(x = 0, y = 0) {
  this.x = x,
  this.y = y;

  if (!Something.prototype.isSet) {
    // you will see this once
    console.log("setting prototype methods");
    initializePrototype(Something, {
      point: function(x = this.x, y = this.y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
      },
      setColor: function(color = "#000") {
        this.color = color;
      },
      moveRight: function(dx) {
        this.x = dx || this.x;
      },
    });
  }
}

// create a few things
const thingA = new Something(1, 2);
const thingB = new Something(3, 4);
const thingC = new Something();
thingB.setColor('#FFF');
console.log(`thingA => x: ${thingA.x}, y: ${thingA.y}, color: ${
  thingA.color || "not set"}`);
console.log(`thingB => x: ${thingB.x}, y: ${thingB.y}, color: ${
  thingB.color || "not set"}`);
console.log(`thingC => x: ${thingC.x}, y: ${thingC.y}, color: ${
  thingC.color || "not set"}`);
```

Comment: Thanks! In place of 
point: 
function(x, y, color) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.color = color;
    }
can i just put point1 : point
and have the point function outside?

Comment: you can place any function outside. Will add an example

Answer (score 1):

you can create an object of type `Point` and make a copy of its `moveRight` and assign it to `objectWithoutMethods` with `this` inside the copy pointing to `objectWithoutMethods`:

```js
var objectWithoutMethods = {
    x : 4,
    y : 2,
    color : '#392f44'
}

var Point = function(x,y,color)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.moveRight = function(dx)
    {
         this.x += dx;
    }
}

let p = new Point()

for (i in p){
    if(typeof p[i] === 'function'){
          objectWithoutMethods[i] = p[i].bind(objectWithoutMethods)
        }
}

objectWithoutMethods.moveRight(5);

console.log(objectWithoutMethods.x);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, if I have many methods, is there a way to bind all of them to objectWithoutMethods without hardcoding it?